# PHP: When I save JPG image the file extension is always missing

Tags: php, jpeg, imagick, file-extension, file-put-contents

I wrote a tiny script to create previews of all JPG images in a directory and save them into another directory. But the file extension `.jpg` is always missing. I really do not understand why.

```
foreach( glob(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../img/plakate/full/*.jpg") as $img ){

  // key
  $key = basename($img,'.jpg').PHP_EOL;

  // save preview
  $thumb = new Imagick($img);
  $thumb->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
  $thumb->setImageCompressionQuality(10);
  $thumb->resizeImage(50,0,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
  $thumb->writeImage("lib/img/plakate/preview/{$key}.jpg");
  $thumb->destroy();

}
```

I also tried this which results in the same:

```
foreach( glob(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../img/plakate/full/*.jpg") as $img ){

  // key
  $key = basename($img,'.jpg').PHP_EOL;

  // save preview
  $thumb = new Imagick($img);
  $thumb->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
  $thumb->setImageCompressionQuality(10);
  $thumb->resizeImage(50,0,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
  $thumb->setImageFormat('jpeg');
  file_put_contents ("lib/img/plakate/preview/{$key}.jpg", $thumb);
  $thumb->destroy();

}
```

As I see everything works fine – only the file extension is missing. :(

Comment: Might want to remove `.PHP_EOL` from the `$key`. There should be no newline/end of line in the filename

Comment: @kerbholz i marked it as correct answer - thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `$key = basename($img,'.jpg').PHP_EOL;` has a `PHP_EOL` at the end, saying that the line ends here, "discarding" anything after it when assembling your filename.

Change `$key = basename($img,'.jpg').PHP_EOL;` to `$key = basename($img,'.jpg');` to have your file extension appended.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use it instead of  `basename`,

```
$explodedPath = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $img);
$fileName = $explodedPath[count($explodedPath) - 1];
```

or `pathinfo`

```
$pathParts = pathinfo($img);
$fileName = "{$pathParts['filename]}{$pathParts['extension']}"
```